# Referencing caption of code listing

Tags: cross-referencing, listings

I would like to reference some piece of code which has a caption on it like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=componenet \label{Label} , backgroundcolor = \color{lightgray}]
//Here is my code
\end{lstlisting}
```

I reference it somewhere else like `\ref{Label}`, but when I click I get the initial page of my document, so this is not working. Any better idea on how to reference this?

Comment: Try `\begin{lstlisting}[caption=componenet, label=Label, backgroundcolor = \color{lightgray}]` instead.

Comment: @moewe Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: @samcarter Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lstlisting` environment has a `label` key that can be used to give it a `\label`. Just  use

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=componenet, label=Label, backgroundcolor = \color{lightgray}]
//Here is my code
\end{lstlisting}
```